# Sed or awk. Find text between two strings + and additional identifier

Tags: awk, sed

I am looking to search a file and pull out data in between two strings.  I am able to this with sed ok.  But I also need it to only pull that information for a specific field.  Example:

```
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test1 [S=4444] [SID:1630710955] HOOK_EV

---SYSLOG DATA
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test1 [S=4445] [SID:1630710956]
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test1 [S=4444] [SID:1630710955] HOOK_EV_OFF
```

My sed statement can pull data in between the HOOK_EV and HOOK_EV_OFF strings.  However I would like it to only pull data for the specific SID number.  Currently it will pull all data in between the two strings but for everything.  So in the example above I would like to only pull data for the SID:1630710955 in between the HOOK_EV and HOOK_EV_OFF string.

Can sed do all that?

Comment: Would you be opposed to adding in `grep`?  Example: `sed ... | grep 'SID:1630710955'`

Comment: Not at all.  But the SID changes.  So in the same file I would like to organize the data in between the HOOK events by the SID.  So I may not know which SID i am looking for.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: You say you want to pull "data" but you don't tell us what "data" - whole lines, parts of lines or something else? Show more extensive input that includes lines you do NOT want to extract, and include the expected output. Make it something testable we could run a possible solution against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an `awk` onliner:

```
awk -v sid=1630710955 '/HOOK_EV_OFF$/{flag=0;next}{if(flag && $0 ~ "SID:"sid){print}}/HOOK_EV$/{flag=1;next}' infile
```

Explanation:

```
awk -v sid=1630710955 '/HOOK_EV_OFF$/{flag=0;next} # Final pattern found   --> turn off the flag and read next line
                       {if(flag && $0 ~ "SID:"sid){print}} # if flag and SID pattern in line print it
                       /HOOK_EV$/{flag=1;next} # Initial pattern found --> turn on the flag and read the next line
                       ' infile
```

For a dynamic `SID`extraction, you can use:

```
awk '/HOOK_EV_OFF$/{flag=0;SID="";next} 
     flag && $NF==SID
     /HOOK_EV$/{flag=1;SID=$(NF-1);next}' infile
```

Having this input file:

```
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test1 [S=4444] [SID:1630710955] HOOK_EV
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test1 [S=4445] [SID:1630710955]
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test1 [S=4445] [SID:1630710956]
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test1 [S=4444] [SID:1630710955] HOOK_EV_OFF
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test1 [S=4445] [SID:1630710955]
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test2 [S=4444] [SID:1630710965] HOOK_EV
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test2 [S=4447] [SID:1630710965] 
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test2 [S=4447] [SID:1630710967] 
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test2 [S=4444] [SID:1630710965] HOOK_EV_OFF
```

The output will be:

```
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test1 [S=4445] [SID:1630710955]
2015-04-29T08:05:24.668345-04:00 test2 [S=4447] [SID:1630710965]
```

Comment: Could awk do this for every SID in the file.  So lets say the SID only contains numerical characters from 9-10 digits.  Is awk able to pull the data for every SID?  I'm guessing I would need some kind of regexp to achieve this?

Comment: whitespace is not a rare commodity: you should think about using some.

Comment: Best I can tell the 2 `next` and the `SID=""` statements are doing nothing.

Comment: Just a safety habit @EdMorton but yes, it can be omitted.

Comment: Nice job figuring out what the OP wanted, btw, I had no clue until you posted your solution and the OP told us it was correct!

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n '/HOOK_EV$/,/HOOK_EV_OFF$/ {/SID:1630710955/p}'
```